# Self join query with references in other tables

Tags: join

I have tried a series of joins and queries to get the result I am looking for with no success.

I have three tables with the following columns:
Attributes

- ID, KEY, VALUE
  Book
- BID
  PAGE
- PID, BID

The ID in Attributes refers back to either the Book or page table as such
ID - KEY - VALUE
a1 - A - Book1
a2 - B - Page1

The BOOK table simple holds a record of the book and its associated pages
BID - PID
a1 - p1
a1 - p2

Page id is similar but swapped
PID - BID
p1 - a1
p2 - a1

I need to query the attributes table to get the book name and then count how many pages are associated with it

select b.VALUE as "book", COUNT(p.VALUE) as "PAGE COUNT
from attributes b, attributes p
inner join book k on k.PID = p.ID
where b.key = 'A' and p.KEY = 'B' groub by b.value;

I am getting a result, but its incorrect. Here is a table example and the result I am looking for.

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ndmn.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ot5Jx.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.value as book, count(p.pid) as page_count
from book b, page p, attributes a
where b.bid = p.bid
and b.bid = a.id
and a.key = 'A'
group by a.value
```

Comment: WORKED PERFECTLY! thank you. I was over complicating it.

Comment: @EricT great! Please mark answer as accepted then :)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT COUNT(pages.pid) FROM pages JOIN books ON books.bid = pages.pid JOIN attributes ON attributes.id = books.bid WHERE books.bid = book_id